# Use phoneapplicationpage in .cs file : Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is the code which I wrote in .xaml file to display the Application Bar.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton  IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/back.png" Text="Previous" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton  IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/save.png" Text="Save" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_3"/>

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/next.png" Text="Next" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

but when I added a Vserv ad, it disabled the application bar and after that the bar is not displayed at all.

I am a starter in Windows Phone Development. Can you help me to convert this code in C# so that I can use it in the .cs file after the ad is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i guess right. you can add application in .cs file

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
    ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0; 
    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
    ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

    ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
    button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
    button1.Text = "button 1";
    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1);

    ApplicationBarMenuItem menuItem1 = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
    menuItem1.Text = "menu item 1";
    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
```

Comment: it worked the way i want with a little modification. thanks a lot. :-)